# Let $k$ be an odd integer and $A$ and $B$ real symmetric matrices with $A^k=B^k$, then $A=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric real $n\times n$ matrices such that $A^k=B^k$, then $A=B$.

Is my proof correct?

Take $\lambda\in \mathbb R$, then $A(v)=\lambda v\implies A^k(v)=\lambda^kv$.

Since the sum of the dimensions of the eigenvalue spaces of $A$ is $n$, we can be exactly sure that $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^k$ if and only if $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda^{\frac{1}{k}}$ of $A$ (and $B$).

Therefore $A$ and $B$ have exactly the same eigenvalue spaces, so we can take a basis of eigenvectors such that $A$ and $B$ coincide for each vector of the basis.$_\boxminus$

Comment: I think I only used that $A$ and $B$ are diagonizable.

Comment: $\lambda^3$ should be $\lambda^k$.

Comment: of course, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the eigenvalues are real (otherwise why does $\lambda ^k$ determine $\lambda$?)

Comment: @mathguy Since these are real symmetric matrices, that assumption is true.  More generally, the proof works for matrices that are diagonalizable over the reals.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - yes, I missed "real" at the very top, I just saw "symmetric." I edited the title to include "real" there as well.

Comment: @mathguy Symmetric matrices are, by definition, real.

Comment: @GitGud - that is not the definition I know (and have used); "symmetric" can be defined for matrices over any ring.

Comment: @mathguy Though the "symmetric property" makes sense in a whole lot of places, only once in my life have I seen it not defined restricted to the real numbers.

Comment: @GitGud - that says more about you than about the definition of symmetric matrices. For example, run a quick Google search on "Autonne-Takagi factorization". Just one example: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241713135_A_generalization_of_the_complex_Autonne-Takagi_factorization_to_quaternion_matrices

Comment: @mathguy You can always say my perception of things says more about me than it says about things themselves. But if you google *symmetric matrix* you yourself will see how hard it is to find a different definition than what I said.

Comment: Very interesting conversation, anyways, does the proof look ok?

Comment: @GitGud - sorry, my point was exactly that... what a definition is shouldn't be based on what a Google search shows. I have taught the Autonne-Takagi factorization many years ago, that is why I was skeptical of the problem here (my mistake, I didn't see "real" in the title and then missed it in the body) and also why I reacted like that to your comment about definition. Didn't mean it to be offensive.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I know this isn't what you're asking, but if you care, it's easier to prove the result using the fact that symmetric matrices are $\mathbb R$-diagonalizable.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling - yes, the proof looks fine! I am not even sure you need the argument about dimensions - you showed that every eigenvector of A is also an eigenvector of B. So if you use a basis of eigenvectors of A, both A and B will be diagonal at the same time. That's all you need.

Comment: The result is also true under the assumption that $A$ and $B$ have real eigenvalues and are invertible (without requiring them to be symmetric).  On the other hand, if you require neither invertibility nor symmetry a counterexample is $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0}$, $B = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your solution is correct and complete.